# What is the "screen of the cable" for medium/high voltage cables?

Tags: wire, cables, high-voltage

I heard that for medium and high voltage cable, there is something called "screen of cable". What does this "screen" do in the cable? Why is it part of the cable construction?

Comment: Ref Wiki : A shielded cable or screened cable is an electrical cable of one or more insulated conductors enclosed by a common conductive layer. ... The shield minimizes capacitively coupled noise from other electrical sources.

Answer (score 7):

In high voltage cables, especially underground, the cable is shielded, or screened, with an earth conductor.

If a digger, or something similar, should cut through the cable it will generally connect the conductive inner core directly with the protective screen around the outside causing the fuse to blow at the substation (or whatever feeds the power) rather than travelling up through the digger and killing the operator.

[image]

In those cables, from the inside out, you have the power conductor(s) (aluminium), insulation (white), plastic sheath (black), copper shielding (orange), more plastic sheath (black), armouring (steel wires), and finally the outer plastic sheath (black).

Comment: Thanks a lot Majenko. so shield is also a conductor which is connected to earth, it means it plays a protective role

Comment: Correct. Note that the shield is a separate thing to the armour which is designed to physically protect the cable from damage.

Answer (score 1):

To supplement Majenko's answer:

This is a labelled diagram of all the layers in a three-core, steel wire armoured cable. The diagram is from Olex Australia's HV catalogue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ref Wiki : A shielded cable or screened cable is an electrical cable of one or more insulated conductors enclosed by a common conductive layer. ... The shield minimizes capacitively coupled noise from other electrical sources.

It also minimizes EMI from a fault current as well as minimizes induction from major class X solar flares that [create magnetosphere wobble](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x31mr0v) and may create havoc on the grid ( and may damage satellites and other communication electronics.)

In addition to this , tri-phase grid transmission lines have phase wires rotated every km to also reduce the same CM noise from lightning and magentosphere wobble currents. This is share equal distance to earth and is similar to the benefits of twisted pairs.

It also provides mechanical strength and some moisture protection to the dielectric insulation from Partial Discharge and transient faults from spring thaw in buried cable due to tiny amounts of moisture absorption in plastic sheath.

There are many variations and other benefits of HVAC shielding.